# Shadows Trembling in Unity ARFoundation while ImageTracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, ar-foundation

When I use Image Tracking in my project the shadows start trembling in the 3D object. When the object is in a random postion, without tracking, it is ok.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OjHcL1mCCc